# Getting certificate chain from TLS for using OCSP

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ocsp

I would like to use OCSP checking for the certificate which is coming from the server during TLS handshake.

I am using Bouncy Castle as provider for OCSP implementation and BC verification methods want X509Certificate as parameter generally.

So; how can I follow and get incoming certificate chain at Java side and fetch it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HttpsURLConnection.getServerCertificates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getServerCertificates()) and cast the result to X509Certificate

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = ...
Certificate chain[] = connection.getServerCertificates();
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this class needs hostname to open connection via url. But I am trying to make TLS with an IP address and I get an error like; _"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 47.168.116.8 found"_ Is it possible to open connection using an IP address?

Comment: HTTPSUrlConnection can work with an IP or with a hostname. In your case the error is due to the fact that to open an SSL connection to a host, the certificate must explicitly include in the SubjectAlternativesNames the IP of the server. It the IP is not included or the hostname does not match with the hostname included in the certificate, the Java client will reject the connection. This error is not related with your original question